# Put dataframes below each other

Tags: dataframe

I have two data frames that I want to put below each other (see screenshots)

```
series1 = df_new[['hour', 'minute','value']]
series2 = df_new[['hour', 'minute','value.1']]
```

[image]
[image]

I tried to use the command

```
a= pd.concat([series1, series2])
```

and I get this instead of the dataframes below each other, no idea why I get nan values. Can you help me with that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
pd.concat([series1,series2.rename(columns={'value.1':'value'})], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, however,I still get the same result!

Comment: THe is problem is because the columns names differs, I updated my code to correct that

Comment: Thanks for the anwer it works! However, if I have also an extra df let's say "series2"  with "value.2". How will it be?? I am soryy I am a beginner and cannot find it thanks again, appreciate it! I tried this but get the same problem c = pd.concat([series1, series2, series3.rename(columns={'value.1 ,value.2':'value'})], ignore_index=True)